# how to get max value by the indices return by torch.max?

Tags: python, pytorch, max, tensor

The interface torch.max will return value and indices， how can i use the indices to get the according elements  from another tensor?
for example:

```
a = torch.rand(2,3,4)
b = torch.rand(2,3,4)
# indices shape is [2, 4]
indices = torch.max(a, 1)[1]
# how to get elements by indices ?
b_max = ????
```

Answer (score 1):

`keepdim=True` when calling `torch.max()` and [`torch.take_along_dim()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.take_along_dim.html) should do the trick.

```py
>>> import torch
>>> a=torch.rand(2,3,4)
>>> b=torch.rand(2,3,4)
>>> indices=torch.max(a,1,keepdim=True)[1]
>>> b_max = torch.take_along_dim(b,indices,dim=1)
```

2D example:

```py
>>> a=torch.rand(2,3)
>>> a
tensor([[0.0163, 0.0711, 0.5564],
        [0.4507, 0.8675, 0.5974]])
>>> b=torch.rand(2,3)
>>> b
tensor([[0.7542, 0.1793, 0.5399],
        [0.2292, 0.5329, 0.2084]])
>>> indices=torch.max(a,1,keepdim=True)[1]
>>> torch.take_along_dim(b,indices,dim=1)
tensor([[0.5399],
        [0.5329]])
```